# Scala, find largest list in a list

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Lets say val a = List[List[int]]:
What is the cleanest way to find the list that contains the most amount of elements in Scala?

Answer (score 5):

Try one of `.maxBy` or `.maxByOption`

```
List(List(0)).maxBy(_.size) // List(0)
List(List(0)).maxByOption(_.size) // Some(List(0))
List.empty[List[Int]].maxByOption(_.size) // None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List(List(1), List(2, 3)).maxBy(_.size)
```